# Access dsum textbox with multiple fields

Tags: ms-access

In an Access form, I have a textbox with a control source as follows:
=DSum("Site","tbl_data","Fin_Year='2010' and Qtr='Q1' and IDx='2.2b', IDx='2.4',IDx='2.6a''")

I want to get the total using the dsum function from 3 specified fields in IDx but it returns #Error.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the correct syntax:

```
=DSum("Site","tbl_data","Fin_Year='2010' And Qtr='Q1' And (IDx='2.2b' Or IDx='2.4' Or IDx='2.6a')")
```

or:

```
=DSum("Site","tbl_data","Fin_Year=2010 And Qtr='Q1' And (IDx='2.2b' Or IDx='2.4' Or IDx='2.6a')")
```